# Git ignore multiple files patterns not working

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a problem with git ignore configuration, i have a project with multiple folders with files that i would like to ignore. Here is my structure :

```
backend/modules/{module}/views/{views}/*.php
```

Inside those folders I have some files like index_builder.php, form_builder.php

I want to ignore those generated files but i cant do it using any pattern !
I tried all the solutions available online with no success : 
Here is the pattern that i am using :

```
**/*_builder\*.php
```

What i am doing wrong ?!

Comment: Why is there a \ in there?

Comment: Oops u are right the \ does not exist my bad just the text area field does not show * if i dont add \.

Comment: The pattern `*_builder*.php` should suffice. Are those files already tracked? If so, listing them in an ignore file has no effect: ignore files only ignore *untracked* files. (Ignore is sort of the wrong word. A better word might be "if these files are untracked, do not complain about them being untracked, and when using git add, don't add them either, and in a few special cases, feel free to clobber these files". But `.git_if_these_files_are_untracked_do_not_complain_that_they_are_untracked_and_do_not_add_them_and...` would be too long, so `.gitignore` it is.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, so how can i ignore them without adding to git tracked files ?